# Is this an example of STM32G0 core lockup during software reset?

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, stm32g

Using a STM32G0F06

I have a bootloader/application that I am debugging. I am facing a strange problem. Often, I command the app to drop to bootloader (via a software reset). When I execute the software reset code, occasionally the core locks up.

Here is a video showing the core registers and the disassembly as I step debug through the reset code:

https://youtu.be/8SxjNWpSIss

A couple of questions:

- Is this a MCU core lockup? If not, what is it? Does the PC go to
  0x1FFF19A6 during a core lockup, or is that just random?
- How come the IWDG I have configured does not reset the MCU after it has locked up?
- Does it get locked up to? Is there some way I can programmatically recover from a core lockup:

  - MCU pulls its' own external reset pin low?

Comment: `0x1FFF19A6` is in the "System Memory" block, which contains the device's built-in bootloader. Have you configured any of the `nBOOTx` bits in the Option byte and/or pulled the BOOT0 pin high?

Comment: That makes sense!  Looking at the datasheet, that address is located in the "System Memory" block indeed.  I have SET all the nBOOTx pins, and I have a 5.6k pulldown resistor on the BOOT0 pin